# CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget Keep failling

Tags: c++

Okay I am creating A d2dwindow that can render another surfaces
so i did that

```
HR(D3D10CreateDevice
(
    NULL,
    D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
    &D3dDevicePtr
));

HR(D3dDevicePtr->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&DXGIDevicePtr));
D3dDevicePtr->Release();
```

and after that

```
IDXGISurface* DXGISurfacePtr;
ID2D1RenderTarget* SurfaceRTPtr;

//init the Surface
{
    DXGI_SURFACE_DESC Desc = { 500, 500, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT , {1 , 0} };

    HR(DXGIDevicePtr->CreateSurface(&Desc, 1, DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT, NULL, &DXGISurfacePtr));
    Surfaces.emplace_back(DXGISurfacePtr);
}

//init the RT
{
    FLOAT dpiX;
    FLOAT dpiY;
    D2dFacory->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);

    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props =
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
            D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
            D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED),
            dpiX,
            dpiY
        );
    HR(D2dFacory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(DXGISurfacePtr, props, &SurfaceRTPtr));

    RTs.emplace_back(SurfaceRTPtr);
}
```

but the creating of rt keep failling i tried alot of values like tring every compination in D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES but there is nothing

and i tried that too

```
    float dpiX;
    float dpiY;
    D2dFacory->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);

    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES Prop =
    {
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        {
            DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT,
            D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT
        },
        dpiX,
        dpiY,
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
        D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_10
    };

    HR(D2dFacory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(DXGISurfacePtr, &Prop, &SurfaceRTPtr));

    RTs.emplace_back(SurfaceRTPtr);
```

Comment: Which api keep failing? What is the error?

Comment: CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget IS KEEP FAILLING

Comment: kepp give me thee parameter is not correct

Comment: but i tried alot of options in D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES  but nothing is fixing it

Comment: btw thank u for ansering my question and sry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the problem is the surface and the d2d api was not from the same dxgi so to solve that i followed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts
but there was some diffrances like it use core window not normal one
and it alittle bit messy with api1 or 2 or 3
like ID2D1Device or ID2D1Device1 or ID2D1Device2
so take care when any one try to follow it
and tnk every one who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same issue as I had, here is the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339645/12163761

The problem is that you create device with flag NULL here D3D10CreateDevice

Here is a possible fix

```
HR(D3D10CreateDevice
(
    NULL,
    D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
    D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
    &D3dDevicePtr
));
```